# How to load a tableView with an array of dictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I want to load a table view with an array which itself has multiple dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries has items which I need to put into a row, one dictionary per row. All of these dictionaries are stored in an array.

How should I perform this task?

Thanks,

See the code below, projects is my array.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   // id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return self.projects.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code up to the point you're stuck?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pretty much what you have. You'll just need to change your `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method to look something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"some_key"];
```

Just change `some_key` to the key in your `NSDictionary` that you want to display in your `UITableViewCell`.

You can also change your `UITableViewCell` style to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` and then you can add another key from your `NSDictionary` to `cell.detailTextLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to edc1591,

In case if the dictionaries in the array have different keys then

```
  if([[self.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count]==1)

   {
     id key= [[[self.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
     cell.textLabel.text = [[self.projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key];
   }
```